# PHPlist urls in email body changed to clicktrack urls

Tags: url, phplist

I have clicktrack turned off, however text only messages with url links in them are having the url's changed to a clicktrack url's. That is they point back to "mywebsite.com" and not the intended url link.

I have searched google and found people (this year 2014) having similar problems but no answers.

All the clicktrack settings in the config files are correct "off"  (does not seem that complicated)

changing them to html ref just leaves me with the href label which is not clickable (might be a clue but not sure), and I actually want to send text email not html.

Has anyone else had this problem, or any ideas on solutions?

Comment: After much messing around the answer was to remove the http:// from the links

Answer (score 0):

I added the following settings to try to solve and it seems it works
    # Usertrack
    # Usertrack is used to track views or opens of campaigns. This only works in HTML messages
    # as it relies on a little image being pulled from the phpList system to update the database
    # To add it to your campaigns, you need to add [USERTRACK] somewhere. 
    # From version 3 onwards, this is automatically done with the following setting. If you do not
    # want it, you can switch it off here, by uncommenting the next line
    define('ALWAYS_ADD_USERTRACK',0);

```
# Click tracking
# If you set this to 1, all links in your emails will be converted to links that
# go via phpList. This will make sure that clicks are tracked. This is experimental and
# all your findings when using this feature should be reported to mantis
# for now it's off by default until we think it works correctly
define('CLICKTRACK',0);
```